# Android: Button state changed event

Tags: android

Some XML attributes of buttons (such as background, textColor, etc) can be defined with color or drawable state List like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> 
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
          android:color="#ff00ffff"/> 
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> 
</selector>
```

When view state changes (pressed/unpressed, for example), corresponding color is changed automatically.

How can I prograqmmatically handle some kind of stateChangedEvent to perform more complicated layout change, than just changing a color (for example, change font size or set another text)?

Comment: BASICALLY U WANNA SHOW THAT  WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED IT HAS BEEN  PRESSED?

Comment: so is there no listener to listen to onSelected?  it can happen without click, due to some other part of the program callin setSelected(bool). like, without doing a custom button class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For focus changes and touch events you can register listeners by setOnFocusChangeListener and setOnTouchListener. And changes about disabled/enabled states you can perform directly after changing your button state.

Comment: Look's like there is no any common way to handle all the changes at once?

Comment: One listener to all events? What for? :) If so, than you need to write handler for huge number of event even if you need only focus changed one.
Btw, you may want to try write your own custom view for button.

Comment: The ones selector is triggering on, of cause. Look like something inside Button class should call some kind of "UpdateColorStateList()", when it needs to update background on press/focus/select/etc., for example. I want to trigger this.

Comment: Create your class that extends Button and override drawableStateChanged like this:
`@Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        Log.d("TEST", String.format("button focused: %s, enabled: %s, pressed: %s",
                isFocused() ? "yes" : "no", isEnabled() ? "yes" : "no", isPressed() ? "yes" : "no"));
        super.drawableStateChanged();
    }
`
and watch `adb logcat TEST:* *:S`.
I think this exactly what you need.

Comment: @muffinmad Best answer yet! Solved my button issues, and is more immediate in invalidating than using OnTouchListener etc.

Answer (score 4):

// use the selector method to pass your button and image
// you  can use color also

```
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

//      b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        selector(b1, R.drawable.image_1_2, R.drawable.image_1);
      //  selector(b2, R.drawable.image_2_2, R.drawable.image_2);


    }

    public void selector(Button b,int pressed_image,int normal_image )
    {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            getResources().getDrawable(pressed_image));         
       states.addState(new int[] { },
            getResources().getDrawable(normal_image));      
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just override View.setPressed:

```
@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    super.setPressed(pressed);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handler onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) for specific views and perform actions in MotionEvent.DOWN / Up according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a reference to the View Object (button) via `findViewById(<object_id>)` and than use the appropriate methods from the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

For example:

private Button aButton;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);   

    aButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

    //example 1
    aButton.setVisibility(SomeExpressionEvaluation ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); 

    //example 2
    if (SomeExpressionEvaluation) { 
        aButton.setText("Some Text");
    }
```

and so on, just take a look at the API, especially inherited methods from the View class.

Answer (score 0):

I must say you can use a (touch listner) this how u use a touch listner

```
image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

find ur image first

Add a touch Listner to ur image

```
 image.setOnTouchListener(image_onTouch);
```

//Add a touch method which is by name image_onTouch

```
OnTouchListener image_onTouch=new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0,MotionEvent arg1){
        int iAction=arg1.getAction();

        if(iAction==0){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
        else{
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

// image 1 is ur image which u want 2 click and image 2 is the image when you touch that image you have to make an another image in which background color do u wanna show and use it in the code

Answer (score 0):

I had also this kind of problem in past. I solved by putting this XML file in separate drawable folder in Res instaed of drawable-mdpi or else. And make sure that you have to give this Xml as your button's background.