# How to dynamically set selector to image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Hi i want to set selector to image through code. I have a selector which diff images for diff image view state . There is a way to set selector through xml file but i want to set it on button click .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/kanal_bogen_rund" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/kanal_bogen_rund_rollover" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/kanal_bogen_rund_rollover" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/kanal_bogen_rund" />
</selector>
```

My Code is :-

```
img.setImageResource(R.layout.my_button);
```

Or there is any way to change image on focus/hover in android?

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518266/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector depends on view's state. 
For example set this view focused:

```
myView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

and the first item with `state_focused="true"` will be used.

If you want to switch drawables programmaticaly then use Level List:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList