# What is the best strategy to have a button that when the finger is pressing on it has one image and when not, another image?

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have an ImageView with an image, and an onclicklistener, and the image is working like a button.

I need to add another image for when the button is pressed by a finger. I thought to do this:

```
movement.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (movement_mode){
                        movement_mode=false;
                        movement.setImageBitmap(Util.loadImage("/desplaz_inactivo"));                
                    }
                    else{
                        movement_mode=true;
                        movement.setImageBitmap(Util.loadImage("/desplaz_activo"));
                    }
                }
            });
```

But I think that this is not a fair way to achieve it... I think there must be another easy and fast way to achieve this.

**Please, tell me NON XML strategies, I'm programming without using XML files for the layouts.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518266/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
pagelist= new ImageButton(this);
        selector(pagelist, R.drawable.but_pagelist_up,R.drawable.but_pagelist_down);
        rl.addView(pagelist);

public void selector(ImageButton b, int normal_image, int pressed_image)
    {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            getResources().getDrawable(pressed_image));         
       states.addState(new int[] { },
            getResources().getDrawable(normal_image));      
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
    }
```