# How to set the text_selector at the run time

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using the following selector

text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>    
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

I am using the following  code to set the selector at the runtime

```
txtMainlabel.setTextColor(R.color.text_selector);
```

Comment: progrmatically using selector http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518266/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your selector under res/drawable and use

```
label.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.text_selector));
```

don't forget to set `android:clickable="true"` in the declaration of your TextView in the layout

Comment: @V.P. see the updated answer ;) also your white color may not appear if you don't use a dark background for the text view

Comment: :-means?i can't understand your answer

Comment: i set the my textview in a static inner class

Answer (score 0):

```
txtMainlabel.setTextColor(R.color.text_selector);
```

setTextColor is expecting an integer corresponding to the color value. What you are doing is attributing a color with integer value of R.color.text_selector. You can see on your R file that value. Therefore you are setting always the same color to the view.

To set a color you can do: `setTextColor(Color.white)`.

Also I'm not sure TextView has states, so I'm not sure you can set a selector to a TextView. If it's not an option, You can always set click listeners and set the new colors for those actions.