# Understanding View.drawableStateChanged

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anyone explain when exactly [View.drawableStateChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#drawableStateChanged()) is called? I want to use it in conjunction with [ViewGroup.setAddStatesFromChildren](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#setAddStatesFromChildren(boolean)) to make a complete `ViewGroup` "optically" focused, meaning e.g. change background color when e.g. an `EditText` of this `ViewGroup` gets focus.

When I implement `View.drawableStateChanged` it's called very often, how do I know that the current call is the one I care about? What's the advantage over settings focus listeners on the child Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it simple, you want your whole `Viewgroup` be focused when one of its children is actually focused for that you only need `ViewGroup.setAddStatesFromChildren`
create a `drawable` file i call it **view_focus** in my code :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="19dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/green" android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="19dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

now in your **activity layout** you have to pass the above drawable as a background both in your Viewgroup and its children like the following :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/view_focus"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">
        <EditText
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/view_focus"
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/view_focus"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

in this case `RelativeLayout` parentlayout is the `Viewgroup` and it's children are the two `EditText` if you execute this code only the children will gain `Focus` once clicked, if you want your whole ViewGroup gain Focus your need to add this line in your Activity Class file :

```
relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);
relativeLayout.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

this is the result after using the above line.

[image: after]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fcmn3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/101343329_1387963878258548_4294181334164701184_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_eui2=AeGydr_7TE5mUG9pgDn3psy-kvNdf0ESE-KS811_QRIT4qDDpuoK9M9I_l_NoID_ANwmlTdTXNh-zmvwGkYggTb4&_nc_ohc=lYzNq7GCzWIAX_L8mez&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmn3-1.fna&oh=e82bb984760c8abd667b1e78ba9c4228&oe=5EF8E028))</sub>

and this before using `ViewGroup.setAddStatesFromChildren`
[image: before]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fcmn3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/101407871_534687210532215_3230965577359032320_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_eui2=AeGKzeUobQPJta2Bu3gIVs1iUJ6c45raEIZQnpzjmtoQhrbK1xFX7Z-7evEHUIacW6Pbw7o9MhTDDnBsQuApDzCa&_nc_ohc=f6EuHko6VLUAX_1Z1FQ&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmn3-1.fna&oh=d68c8ef1534f8140d10dcc592a96a388&oe=5EF6F211))</sub>

Comment: thank you, that's the most complete answer for me. bounty awarded! next time your samples need another background than white ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#drawableStateChanged()).

> `View.drawableStateChanged()` is called whenever the state of the view changes in such
> a way that it impacts the state of drawables being shown.

If you create drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> 
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
          android:color="#ff00ffff"/> 
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> 
</selector>
```

This drawable has mainly different states(like `state_pressed`, `state_focused`, `state_enabled`). If you have set drawable to a particular view and that view is clickable then when you click on of that view, this state generally changes.

You can use `setOnFocusChangeListener` to check about focus changes and `setOnTouchListener` touch events.
Also, you can check to enable/disable the state `onClick()` event of that view.

Update: This method is deprecated, please follow [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#drawableStateChanged()) for more.

Comment: link is not working

Answer (score 0):

From reading through the documentation which states:

```
This function is called whenever the state of the view changes in 
such a way that it impacts the state of drawables being shown.
```

It seems that this function will be called by the framework whenever the component needs to be redrawn and you can override it to (for example) perform so application specific logic which you need to do when the component is redrawn, like manually drawing something over the top of the component, or changing the font or doing something which is not possible using the stock attributes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20933209/6160172) has an example of how you might implement it.